# ASP.NET Core 3.1 AddHttpClient call that includes a call to the database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So, I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 web site that makes occasional calls to a vendor's RESTful API. I use the `HttpClient` class to perform these calls.

Currently, the web site is relatively low traffic (probably a couple of users per day). The current primary use case will result in 3 calls to the API for the complete workflow.

Even in previous versions of the framework, Microsoft [recommended](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) just creating a single instance of `HttpClient` and using it throughout the entire lifecycle of your application (to prevent port exhaustion). The new [recommendation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for ASP.NET Core is to register a service in your `Startup` class to act as a factory for your `HttpClient`. I initially used my own Singleton for but recently switched to follow Microsoft's recommendation.

My one concern is that I have to add my API Key as a header for each request, or it will be rejected.

I currently store the database key in SQL Server, using its [always-encrypted feature](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) to make sure that it stays private.

Here's the relevant logic in the `ConfigureServices` method in my `Startup` class:

```
services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>();

// Use TLS 1.3 for requests
// I'm a little uncertain if this is still the recommended way to configure this in ASP.NET Core
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;

services.AddHttpClient("VendorAPICall", c =>
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.vendorname.com/");

            c.Timeout = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);

            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

            c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");

            // I store the API Key securely using SQL Server's Always Encrypted feature: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15
            // I'm a little concerned about the potential performance impact of this, especially how
            // many extra database calls it could result in (particularly since I'm not doing
            // the async calls).
            using (var ctx = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                Security security = ctx.Security.First();

                // Header must include the API Token for all requests, or the request will be rejected 
                c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiToken", security.Apikey);
            }
        });
```

I have two points that I'm concerned about:

First, is the call to `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls13;` still the recommended (or, at least, acceptable) way of doing this configuration in ASP.NET Core, or am I doing this wrong?

Secondly, I'm concerned about the database call and how many back-and-forths this could result in for the database. This seems a little unnecessary, since the API Key will only be renewed every 6 months or so, so it seems wasteful at a minimum and a potential scalability issue at worst.

I'm also a little annoyed that I'm not using the `async` version of the Entity Framework calls here. (I'm otherwise using the async version of all of the database calls wherever possible).

Am I worrying too much here, or is there actually a better way to do this? (I [already established](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571926/does-microsoft-have-a-recommended-way-to-handle-secrets-in-headers-in-httpclient) in a separate Q&A on Stack Overflow that I was, in fact, being paranoid about the possibility of keeping the API Key in memory, but that's probably a separate issue).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to manually create the DbContext. Since you have already registered it with the service collection, resolve it as needed.

[`AddHttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientfactoryservicecollectionextensions.addhttpclient) has an overload that provides access to the service provider.

```
services.AddHttpClient("VendorAPICall", (sp, c) => {
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.vendorname.com/");
    c.Timeout = new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0);
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    var ctx = sp.GetService<DatabaseContext>(); //<-- resolve context
    Security security = ctx.Security.First();
    // Header must include the API Token for all requests, 
    // or the request will be rejected 
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ApiToken", security.Apikey);

});
```

This will allow the framework to manage its lifetime instead of constantly having to dispose of it yourself in a `using` block

Comment: Thanks, seems like that alone will save resources. Once I have that, I can assume that the db call itself isn't all *that* terrible of overhead?

Comment: Congrats on getting close vote rights on this site too BTW :)

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica Glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

Let me reflect to your other question, which is related to the good old `ServicePointManager`.

In the early versions of .NET Core they tried to get rid of the `ServicePointManager` and the related `HttpWebRequest` class as well. Instead they have introduced two new classes: `WinHttpHandler` and `CurlHandler`. Former should be used in Windows environment and latter should be used everywhere else.

So prior .NET Core 2.0, you had to write something like this:

```
var httpHandler = new WinHttpHandler();
httpHandler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls13;
var httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
```

But in .NET Core 2.0 it was reintroduced but in a slightly different way. Please read [this excellent article](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/httpclient-connection-pooling-in-dotnet-core) if you are interested about the details.

So, in short: Yes, you can still use in .NET Core 3 the `ServicePointManager`, which now resides inside the [System.Net.ServicePoint.dll](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.servicepointmanager.securityprotocol).